# Photofilmstrip not starting on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

After a fresh install on Ubuntu 20.04, Photofilmstrip does not start. From terminal I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/photofilmstrip", line 8, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/photofilmstrip/GUI.py", line 46, in main
guiApp.Start()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/photofilmstrip/AppMixin.py", line 41, in Start
self.InitI18N()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/photofilmstrip/AppMixin.py", line 31, in InitI18N
ActionI18N().Execute()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/photofilmstrip/action/ActionI18N.py", line 43, in Execute
lang.install(True)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/gettext.py", line 352, in install
   for name in allowed & set(names):
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Any idea? I'm working with Python 3.8

Comment: This is fixed [upstream](https://github.com/PhotoFilmStrip/PFS/pull/64/commits/42ad75a604f4075a0797f78962f7a9b9ff2b5e87), when the Ubuntu maintainer updates the package you'll get the fix. [(Ubuntu bug report)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/photofilmstrip/+bug/1871402)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by installing the deb version 3.7.**3**-1 of photofilmstrip for groovy on UbuntuUpdates.org. It works for me on Linuxmint 20.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/photofilmstrip/action/ActionI18N.py
In line 43, remove True from lang.install(True)